# Adding html around videos prevents Vimeo api from working

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo

i got a page on a site and there are several videos within blocs. When i play one video and then hit the close button or click on another box to open it, it works all just fine. But the problem comes when i add extra html markup around the videos, it breaks the close button behavior.

Here's the markup of a box (i've got multiples in my page):

```
<div class="box" data-size="660,605">
    <div class="cunload2">
        <div class="expandable">
            <span class="simple">
                <a class="cunload" href="javascript:;"></a>
            </span>

            <div class="exandable-vids-container">
                <iframe ... ></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The `cunload` button is the one closing the box and unloading the video.

Here's the javascript (as seing at the [vimeo api's page](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js)):

```
(function(){
    var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), player;

    for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
        player = vimeoPlayers[i];
        $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
    }

    function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
        if (element.addEventListener) { element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false); }
        else { element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false); }
    }

    function ready(player_id) {
        var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode,
            froogaloop = $f(player_id),
            apiConsole = container.querySelector('.console .output');

        function setupSimpleButtons() {
            var unloadBtn = container.querySelector('.simple').querySelector('.cunload');
            addEvent(unloadBtn, 'click', function() { froogaloop.api('unload'); }, false);
        }

        setupSimpleButtons();
        $(".cunload, .box:not(.expanded)").click(function(){
             //if (!$(this).is('expanded')) {
                froogaloop.api('unload');
             //} 
        });
    }
})();
```

This works just fine, but when i add an extra `<div>` around the iframe (and i really need to) it doesnt work anymore.

Any clue?

EDIT: problem is more complicated, i added an `<ul>` and `<li>` tags around the iframes as such:

```
<div class="box" data-size="660,605">
    <div class="cunload2">
        <div class="expandable">
            <span class="simple">
                <a class="cunload" href="javascript:;"></a>
            </span>

            <div class="exandable-vids-container">
                <ul>
                    <li><iframe ... ></iframe></li>
                    <li><iframe ... ></iframe></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

and modified the js line :

```
var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode
```

to:

`var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`

and i got it working.

The problem is that i use the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags to call [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and that it adds an extra 3 divs between my `.exandable-vids-container` and the `<ul>`. Moreover, sometimes i'll call this carousel and sometimes not, so i really can't go with adding extras `.parentNode` in the js. This would have to be dynamic and i think the solution has to be in that direction.